# add tables down on other table with variable name in SAS

Tags: sas

I have 2 sas output tables. First table has a,b,c columns and second table has d,e,f columns
First table is :

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Second table is :

```
d   e   f
7   8   9
```

Is it possible to append them in one sheet with desired output

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
d   e   f
7   8   9
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You mention sheet.  Is the output via ODS Excel ?  What happens if you use `ods excel options (sheet_interval='none')` and two proc prints ?

Comment: Do you want the variable names to append in the table?

Comment: Yes i need variables name in output table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can append the second table to the first using `proc append` , you just need to rename the columns in second table before appending.

```
proc append base=table1 data=table2(rename=(d=a e=b f=c)) ;run;
```

Full Code:

```
data table1;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
;
run;
data table2;
input d e f;
datalines;
7 8 9
;
run;

proc append base=table1 data=table2(rename=(d=a e=b f=c)) ;run;
```

Table1 will look like this after appending:

```
a=1 b=2 c=3 
a=4 b=5 c=6 
a=7 b=8 c=9
```

Another Option: If all your data is characters, you just need a create a third table to hold the column names you want to append.

Full Code:

```
data table1;
input a $ b $ c $;
datalines;
1 2 3
4 5 6
;
run;
data table2;
input d $ e $ f $;
datalines;
7 8 9
;
run;
data table2_names;
input d $ e $ f $;
datalines;
d e f
;
run;

proc append base=table1 data=table2_names(rename=(d=a e=b f=c)) ;run;
proc append base=table1 data=table2(rename=(d=a e=b f=c)) ;run;
```

Output:

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
a=4 b=5 c=6
a=d b=e c=f 
a=7 b=8 c=9
```

Comment: But variables are different in both tables, i can't rename name, i just need to add second table with variable name

Comment: You can do this but all the columns will have to be character instead of number. `proc append base=table1 data=table2 ;run;`

Comment: If all columns are not number, then Is there any way for this?

Comment: Is this possible for mixture of both numeric and char variables?

Comment: Yes, The source columns can be of different types (we can convert num to char but not char to num), but The target / final table each column will be either numeric or character.